# How can i calculate population in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, logic

I have a data set like this:-

```
S.No.,Year of birth,year of death
1,  1,  5
2,  3,  6
3,  2,  -
4,  5,  7
```

I need to calculate population on till that years let say:-

```
year,population
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   3
5   4
6   3
7   2
8   1
```

How can i solve it in pandas?
Since i am not good in pandas.
Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: 1. covert the year to data_time index using `pd.to_datetime`. 2. and then sort the year you want. 3. using `df[columns].sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is necessary choose maximum year of `year of death` if not exist, in solution is used `8`.

Then convert values of `year of death` to numeric and replace missing values by this year. In first solution is used difference between `birth` and `death` column with [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), for count is used [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
#if need working with years
#today_year = pd.to_datetime('now').year

today_year = 8
df['year of death'] = pd.to_numeric(df['year of death'], errors='coerce').fillna(today_year)


df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['year of death'].add(1).sub(df['Year of birth']).astype(int))]
df['Year of birth'] += df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() 

df1 = (df['Year of birth'].value_counts()
                          .sort_index()
                          .rename_axis('year')
                          .reset_index(name='population'))
print (df1)
   year  population
0     1           1
1     2           2
2     3           3
3     4           3
4     5           4
5     6           3
6     7           2
7     8           1
```

Another solution use list comprehension with `range` for repeat years:

```
#if need working with years
#today_year = pd.to_datetime('now').year

today_year = 8
s = pd.to_numeric(df['year of death'], errors='coerce').fillna(today_year)


L = [x for s, e in zip(df['Year of birth'], s) for x in range(s, e + 1)]

df1 = (pd.Series(L).value_counts()
                   .sort_index()
                   .rename_axis('year')
                   .reset_index(name='population'))
print (df1)
   year  population
0     1           1
1     2           2
2     3           3
3     4           3
4     5           4
5     6           3
6     7           2
7     8           1
```

Similar  like before, only is used `Counter` for dictionary for final `DataFrame`:

```
from collections import Counter

#if need working with years
#today_year = pd.to_datetime('now').year

today_year = 8
s = pd.to_numeric(df['year of death'], errors='coerce').fillna(today_year)

d = Counter([x for s, e in zip(df['Year of birth'], s) for x in range(s, e + 1)])
print (d)
Counter({5: 4, 3: 3, 4: 3, 6: 3, 2: 2, 7: 2, 1: 1, 8: 1})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'year':list(d.keys()),
                    'population':list(d.values())})
print (df1)
   year  population
0     1           1
1     2           2
2     3           3
3     4           3
4     5           4
5     6           3
6     7           2
7     8           1
```